# Magento export all image url's

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We have a shop and want to export all products with all the images, but can not get all the image url's (second, third image etc..). We only export one image url from the main image.

Is there a way or a module to export all the image url's?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the products images you would need to do this in a custom function as this is not available by default in the product collection.

Try this -

```
<?php

$_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*'); // ONLY AS EXAMPLE - DONT SELECT ALL ATTRIBUTES, VERY VERY BAD! 

$products = array();
foreach ($_collection as $_product) {

    $products[$_product->getId()]['images'] = array();

    foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {

        $link = (string) Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(500);

        $products[$_product->getId()]['images'][] = $link;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, we have solved this with a module for exporting products

Comment: What extension did you use?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, using System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Profiles.  I found that if I went to System > Import/Export > Export that there is a column for _media_image which will bring down all of the gallery image URLs for each SKU.